# Projection system that use in North America (USA, canada, Mexico, etc) like in Europe use EPSG:3035?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, africa, north-america, asia

Is there a same projection system that use in North America (USA, Canada, Mexico, etc), Asia, and Africa like in Europe use [EPSG:3035](https://epsg.org/crs_3035/ETRS89-extended-LAEA-Europe.html)? which coordinate system or projection in metric system for North America, Asia, and Africa?

Projection system Coordinate Reference System

Comment: There are a lot of CRS. And a lot are projected using meters. You may want to consider if you want shape or distance or other geographic attributes conserved. Maybe you can search here: https://epsg.io/?q=

Comment: Using the *same* meters projection for North America **and** Asia makes no sense. There are continental US, CONUS+Alaska/HI, and Canadian Albers projections, but getting all of NA in one projection is a bridge too far.

Comment: So you want Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projections using a datum centred on the specific continent?

Comment: The thing is something is looking silly, but what we are working on software we need kinda projection of North america which is metric system same as EPSG 3035 in Europe.
I definitely know the some projectiins like EPSG 4956 and epsg:6317 are in metric system and cover almost entire North America,
However, searching that kind of projection for North America, Asia, and Africa which could work same and smooth as EPSG 3035 as in europe.